# Force ransack to keep value in filter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, ransack

I have a custom filter and in the code below just want to pass a param, then I use in somewhere else and it works fine. BUT the filter always resets to `include_blank` value. How do I force it to have `@my_value`?

```
<%= search_form_for @search,
    url: jobs_path,
    builder: SimpleForm::FormBuilder,
    method: :get do |f|
%>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-2">
    <%= f.collection_select :jobs_type,
      (%w(OneJob TwoJob ThreeJob).map do |key|
        OpenStruct.new(text: key.gsub('Job', '').humanize, val: key)
      end),
      :val, @my_value, { include_blank: 'All Job Types' }
    %>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-1">
    <%= f.submit "Apply" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

edit: I want it to have `@my_value` if it's set; otherwise `include_blank` value. `@my_value` is set correctly, debugged it.

edit2: controller -

```
def index
query_params = params[:q]
@search = Job.ransack(query_params)
@my_value = 'One'
respond_to do |format|
      format.js do
        (...)
      end

      format.html
    end
end
```

Comment: how is the controller looking like?

Comment: @BKSpurgeon I'm just setting `@my_value` in the controller action and it's correct value in the view when debugging

Comment: paste in your controller

Comment: @BKSpurgeon done

Comment: try something like this: <%= f.collection_select :jobs_type,    (%w(OneJob TwoJob ThreeJob).map do |key|
        OpenStruct.new(text: key.gsub('Job', '').humanize, val: key)
      end),

      :val, :text , @my_value? {} : {selected: @my_value }
    %>

Comment: it forces first value from the list